# Yii framework how to get an object from find() or findBySql()

Tags: php, object, yii, find

find() and findBySql() both return a string with all the attributes concatenated together, that's not very useful to me.

```
        $customers = Customer::model()->find("
            CONCAT( fName, ' ', lName ) LIKE  ?
            ", array( '%' . $searchVal . '%'));
```

How can I get something useful like an object or array, so I can do something like this?

```
        $str = '';
        foreach ($customers as $customer){
            $str .= "<option>" . $customer->fName . " " . $customer->lName . "</option>" ;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nobody was lobotomized. In fact, there are several functions that can be used to query the db and all of them are useful in different scenarios.

```
find() returns the first row satisfying the specified condition
findByPk() returns the row with the specified primary key
findByAttributes() returns the first row using the specified SQL statement
findBySql() returns the first row using the specified SQL statement
findAll() returns all rows satisfying the specified condition
findAllByPk() returns all rows with the specified primary keys
findAllByAttributes() returns all rows with the specified attribute values
findAllBySql() returns all rows using the specified SQL statement
```

All these functions have their uses, just use the one appropriate for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try FindAll() instead of find().  find() is intended for a single result.

```
    $customers = Customer::model()->findAll("
        CONCAT( fName, ' ', lName ) LIKE  ?
        ", array( '%' . $searchVal . '%'));
```

Answer (score 0):

find returns the first object findAll return list of all objects matching the criteria ... just use what you need ... they do not return strings